# How to avoid error message : ScriptError: Authorization is required to perform that action when publishing

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I have a Google docs addon deployed as a Web add-on of type 'Docs' with authorization 'everyone with the link'.

This addon is opened automatically with the Google docs document.

Every time a new version of the addon is published the users have in the sidebar, there is a message in the sidebar :
*ScriptError: Authorization is required to perform that action.*

Then, they must reload the add-on - but nothing tells them to do so, they have to guess - and they get a confirmation message :
*Update add-on*

Then they have a two page popup prompting them :

*a) to choose a Google account*

*b) to validate the addon authorizations*

**Is there a programmatic way to avoid having these security messages ?**

Ideally one would wish that there are no more such prompts once the addon has been installed by the user.

Comment: Sadly, you can't avoid this message: "Scripts that you have previously authorized will also ask for additional authorization if a code change adds new services. Scripts may not request authorization if you access the script as a web app that runs under the script owner's user identity.". [Source](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization)

Comment: I will try the option : Execute the app as user accessing the web app, which is indicated in the page you refer to, it seems this might help

Comment: Well apparently that could be a solution for a web app but the option is not available for an addon.
However the documentation at [GoogleAppsScript](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization#permissions_and_types_of_scripts) is rather mysterious, it says : Scripts that you have previously authorized will also ask for additional authorization _if a code change adds new services_. What is a new service is not defined at all.

Comment: It seems that a service means : any API not yet used.